# kotlin android room ForeignKey

Tags: android, android-room

I have an two entity A and B in which one of rows is id , next I have entity Test it looks like :

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(
    tableName = "social_group_discount_relations", primaryKeys = ["oneID", "twoId"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = A::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["oneID"],
            onDelete = CASCADE
        ), ForeignKey(
            entity = B::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["twoId"],
            onDelete = CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Test(
    @SerializedName("oneID") val oneID: Long,
    @SerializedName("twoId") val twoId: Long
) : Parcelable
```

Next I want to try get and obcject :

date class AB ( @Embedded val a: A,  @Embedded val b: B)@Parcelize
@Entity(
    tableName = "discount"
)

```
data class Discount(
    @PrimaryKey @SerializedName("id") val id: Long,
    @SerializedName("description") val description: String?,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("rate") val rate: Int?,
    @SerializedName("operator") val operatorId: Long?

) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "social_group_discount")
data class SocialGroupDiscount(
    @PrimaryKey @SerializedName("id") val id: Long,
    @SerializedName("description") val description: String?,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String?,
    @SerializedName("code") val code: String?,
    @SerializedName("operator") val operator: Long?

) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class SocialGroupAndDiscount(
    @Embedded(prefix = "first_") val discount: Discount,
    @Embedded(prefix = "second_") val socialGroupDiscountRelations: SocialGroupDiscountRelations

) : Parcelable


@Parcelize
@Entity(
    tableName = "social_group_discount_relations", primaryKeys = ["socialGroupId", "discountId"],
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["socialGroupId"]),
        Index(value = ["discountId"])
    ],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Discount::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["discountId"],
            onDelete = CASCADE
        ), ForeignKey(
            entity = SocialGroupDiscount::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["socialGroupId"],
            onDelete = CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
open class SocialGroupDiscountRelations(
    @SerializedName("socialgroupid") val socialGroupId: Long,
    @SerializedName("discountid") val discountId: Long
) : Parcelable
```

this is my query :

```
@Query(
        "SELECT discount.id as first_id,discount.name as first_name, discount.rate as first_rate, discount.operatorId as first_operator, discount.description as first_description " +
                " social_group_discount.id as second_id, social_group_discount.name as second_name, social_group_discount.code as second_code, social_group_discount.description as second_description," +
                "social_group_discount.operator as second_operator FROM social_group_discount_relations as AB" +
                " INNER JOIN discount on discount.id=AB.discountId INNER JOIN social_group_discount on social_group_discount.id=AB.socialgroupid"
    )
    fun getAB(): List<SocialGroupAndDiscount>
```

I have a class dicount and socialGroupDiscount in third class I get List ids discountId and groupId and next I want to create object which map this ids to discount and group discount

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61441790/8956604

Answer (score 0):

You can try to look for [many-to-many relationships](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#many-to-many), but I'm not sure you can get what you want with just a Room tools.

Instead you can use not so clean decision with sqlite-query:

1. To use prefix at fields of embedded object to be sure that in the result table fields wouldn't mix:

   `data class AB (@Embedded(prefix = "first_") val a: A,
         @Embedded(prefix = "second_") val b: B
    )`
2. In your DAO put "manual" query to all needed tables, but in that case you have to get all fields of entities A and B and to add them prefixes:

   `@Query("
   SELECT A.id as first_id,A.someField as first_someField, B.id as second_id, B.anotherField as second_anotherField 
   FROM social_group_discount_relations as AB INNER JOIN A on A.id=AB.oneID INNER JOIN B on B.id=AB.twoId
   ")
   fun getAB(): List<AB>`

**UPDATED with example**

Let's say you have class A with fields:

- id
- name

And your class B's structure:

- id
- address
- quantity

Then your data class AB should be:

```
data class AB (@Embedded(prefix = "first_") val a: A,
  @Embedded(prefix = "second_") val b: B
)
```

And your DAO method:

```
@Query("SELECT A.id as first_id,A.name as first_name, 
B.id as second_id, B.address as second_address, B.quantity as second_quantity 
FROM social_group_discount_relations as AB 
INNER JOIN A on A.id=AB.oneID 
INNER JOIN B on B.id=AB.twoId")
fun getAB(): List<AB>
```

Comment: Well, maybe you could clarify - do you have some error (then what is it?) or your query doesn't return anything? Have you changed query given in the answer according to your class A and B structure or got it "as is"?

Comment: @Query("select * From social_group_discount_relations , aWhere discountId = a.id ")
    fun getAB(): List<SocialGroupAndDiscount>  But I get onlu class a I do not have class b

Comment: I haven't understood what you've wrote. It's not connected with my answer. Added example to my answer.

Comment: Sergiy and this I call from dao class Test ?

Comment: Technically you can put this at any dao class. It's just a function. You can even have just one dao for all entities. But if you have dao class Test - so put it there.

Comment: Sergiy I edit my post , this is want I try do , when I try install app a app is not install

Comment: I have A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

Comment: In your SocialGroupAndDiscount class the second field should be SocialGroupDiscount instead of socialGroupDiscountRelations. And check commas in your query, you've missed one

Comment: Then I don't know, I don't see why that solution doesn't work. You can try another way, proposed by Kasım Özdemir in his comment. He described two variants - 1) the same, as mine 2) variant with two @Relation's. It can be simpler for you. Try it.