# andorid room inner join one column from table

Tags: android, android-room

This is my table :

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "profile")
data class Profile(
    @SerializedName("id") @PrimaryKey var id:Long,
    @SerializedName("name") var name :String?,
    @TypeConverters(UserConverter::class)
    @NotNull
    @SerializedName("users") var users :List<Long>?
):Parcelable
```

and this is my second table :

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Long,
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String
) : Parcelable
```

and I want to get this object :

```
data class ProfileWithUsersName(
    val profile: Profile,
    val usersName: List<String>?
)
```

to get this list of objects I do this :

```
fun getProfiles() :List<ProfileWithUsersName>{
    val arrayListTemp = arrayListOf<ProfileWithUsersName>()
    val profiles =  profileDao.getProfiles()
    for(profile in profiles){
        if(profile.users != null) {
            arrayListTemp.add(
                ProfileWithUsersName(
                    profile,
                    userDao.getUsersNameByIds(profile.users!!)
                )
            )
        }else{
            ProfileWithUsersName(
                profile,
                null
            )
        }
    }
    return arrayListTemp.toList()
}
```

it is any changes to do this on one query ?

Comment: How do you use join? You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61441790/8956604)

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I do not have table with relations

Comment: I explained it how to join tables with and without relation

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir I do not understand how I can do this

Answer (score 0):

it could be something like this

```
@Dao
abstract class ProfileDao {

    companion object {
        const val QUERY = "SELECT * FROM profile " +
                "INNER JOIN user " +
                `your condition`
    }

    @Query(QUERY)
    abstract fun getCurrentStep(): List<ProfileWithUsersName>?
    }
}
```

and your profile should be something like this

```
data class ProfileWithUsersName(
        @Embedded val profile: Profile,
        @Embedded val usersName: List<String>?
)
```

Comment: Kostya  I do this :  @Query("SELECT * from profile inner join user WHERE user.id in profile.user")
    fun getProfiles2() but my project is not build

Comment: could you send an error message? your condition should be like this `INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;`

Comment: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
 at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)

Comment: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

Comment: So how a query should look ?

Answer (score 0):

May be that would not be full answer, but why not to get partly answer?

**Notes to your tables' structure**

- It's not so optimal and it would be better not to hold information about users having exact profile in Profile class (better option - to remove this into another table). But let it be.
- With no changes to tables' structure I think your decision with nested queries could be better if you call the function "userDao.getUsersNameByIds(profile.users!!)" just once (but for that you should change logic a little bit). But I think your tables are not too big to invest time into such optimisations.

**As for "do this in one query"**

- Actually I think that there are some chances to succeed in that, but honestly I don't think it worth of it and that query would be faster or more elegant than loops. But it could be a challenge for somebody :)
- Main problem here - is field "users" in your entity "Profile". In SQLite I guess you save it as a String (with the help of UserConverter). For example, if you have list of ids: [111, 222, 333] in SQLite they will be saved as TEXT "111,222,333". So on next step we must somehow JOIN table with such a field an a table, that has INTEGERS 111|222|333.
- That could be done only with casting INTEGER To TEXT and then JOIN tables on condition - casted_value_from_second_table LIKE ["%," + value_from_first_table + ",%]" in pseudocode. Maybe that requires some changes to your TypeConverter. Even if it will be successful, JOIN tables with "LIKE" is not best practice.

**Conclusions**:

- Without changes to tables' structures and if your tables are not very big I think way how you do now - is acceptable. With "one query" (again, with no changes to db tables' structure) it's not regular task, there are several problems that are needed to be solved experimentally - I don't think it worth of it.

P.S. Maybe I don't see some obvious decision, so it's just my personal opinion :)