# How to get data from @relation where child condition

Tags: android, android-room

I want to get data from One to One Relationship using @Relation but with condition for the child

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey public long userId;
    public String name;
    public int age;
}

@Entity
public class Library {
    @PrimaryKey public long libraryId;
    public long userOwnerId;
    public String code;

}
```

```
public class UserAndLibrary {
    @Embedded public User user;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "userId",
         entityColumn = "userOwnerId"
    )
    public Library library;
}
```

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User") // I want to get where library.code = "123"
public UserAndLibrary getUsersAndLibraries();
```

Data that I want is All data From User where library.code = "123"
I know I can use @Embedded, but my data use many same name and I don't want to use prefix. So I wonder how to do this using @Relation

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61441790/8956604

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Relation you cannot set "child" condition.
So your choice if you don't want to deal with tables' joins - is to replace your parent/child classes in `UserAndLibrary`:

```
public class UserAndLibrary {
    @Embedded public Library library;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "userOwnerId",
         entityColumn = "userId"
    )
    public User user;
}
```

and dao:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM library Where code = :code") // now you can set condition
public UserAndLibrary getUsersAndLibraries(String code);
```