# How to access columns of child entity with query while using room relation?

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite, android-room, android-room-relation

I have two entity order and customer. Each order is associated with zero or single customer and each customer is associated with zero or many orders.

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    public long customerId;
    ....
}

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    public String name;
}
```

I wanted to query the order table with the corresponding customer if it exists.

So, I have created the relation following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships).

```
public class OrderAndCustomer {
    @Embedded public Order order;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "customerId",
            entityColumn = "id"
    )
    public Customer customer;
}
```

I can query the list of orders and the corresponding customer using dao.

```
@Dao
public interface OrderDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("select * from `order`")
    List<OrderAndCustomer> getOrderAndCustomer();
}
```

But when I try to access the columns of child entity, I got compile error. For instance, I wanted to query the order where customer name is like ****.

Therefore, my updated query:

```
@Query("select * from `order` where customer.name like '****'")
```

Is it possible to access the attribute of child entity in where clause?

So, the question arises that how the relation works!? I have figure out that it first query the order entity and then query the customer entity. Let me show the correct way If I am wrong.

I have another solution to [query multiple tables](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-multiple-tables) but I am unable to use the relation feature what room provides or I am missing something!

I can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50698610/3751576) answer to use join and mapping to object.

```
public class OrderAndCustomer extends Order {
    public String customerName;
}
```

Query:

```
@Query("select `order`.*, customer.name as customerName from `order` left outer join customer on `order`.customerId = customer.id where customerName like '****'")
List<OrderAndCustomer> getOrderAndCustomer();
```

But, Still have questions.
How do I map all columns of the order and customer table? Do I need to map all columns of customer with `as` in the query or there is another simplified approach available? If both tables has more columns and I need all of the columns of the first and second table to be fetched, then my query will be long enough. I wonder if there is the simplest thing to map both tables without or minimal using of `as` with all columns of the second table.

Help me with the right approach and better available solution.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62484311/12718414) answer your question?